# How can I record pop up in JMeter

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins

I am actually new to JMeter, So my problem is ,I have to test an application which is actually developed in SharePoint technology, while we are passing URL we will get a pop-up where we need to enter USER Name and Password after which we are logged in  .How can I record this or do I need to use other tool.

Comment: If your browser is using jmeter proxy, the popup will too. Did you actually try recording?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot record modal popups with JMeter. If you need to log in to your Sharepoint, first of all determine what [authentication type](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262350.aspx#suppauth) does it use.

Once you figure that out add [HTTP Authorization Manager](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Authorization_Manager) and configure it to send credentials and any other information which may be required.

See [Windows Authentication with Apache JMeter](https://blazemeter.com/blog/windows-authentication-apache-jmeter) guide for more detailed information on how to bypass NTLM and Kerberos authentication challenges in your JMeter test.